# match the dataframe with the list of columns names

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, match

I have two files, the first one contains the dataframe , without columns names:

```
2008-03-13 15  56   0  25  
2008-03-14 10  32  27  45  
2008-03-16 40   8  54  35  
2008-03-18 40   8  63  30  
2008-03-19 45  32  81  25
```

and another file, that contains the list of columns names (except of datetime column) in the following form:
output of `file.read()`

> List(Group, Age, Income, Location)

In my real data, there are much more columns and columns names. Columns of dataframes are ordered as elements of list, i.e. the first column corresponds to Group, the third one to Income and the last one to Location, etc..
So my goal is to name the columns of my dataframe with the elements, containing in this file.
this operation will not work for obvious reasons (datetime columns are not contained in the list, and the list is not formatted in python form):

```
with open(file2) as f:
    list_of_columns=f.read()
df=pd.read_csv(file1, sep='/t', names=list_of_columns)
```

and I already imagine the work of preprocessing with the removing the word List and () from the output of file2, and adding the column datetime in the head of the list, but if you have more elegant and quick solution, let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it this way:

```
import re

fn = r'D:\temp\.data\36972593_header.csv'
with open(fn) as f:
    data = f.read()

# it will also tolerate if `List(...) is not in the first line`
cols = ['Date'] + re.sub(r'.*List\((.*)\).*', r'\1', data, flags=re.S|re.I|re.M).replace(' ', '').split(',')

fn = r'D:\temp\.data\36972593_data.csv'
# this will also parse `Date` column as `datetime`
df=pd.read_csv(fn, sep=r'\s+', names=cols, parse_dates=[0])
```

Result:

```
In [82]: df
Out[82]:
        Date  Group  Age  Income  Location
0 2008-03-13     15   56       0        25
1 2008-03-14     10   32      27        45
2 2008-03-16     40    8      54        35
3 2008-03-18     40    8      63        30
4 2008-03-19     45   32      81        25

In [83]: df.dtypes
Out[83]:
Date        datetime64[ns]
Group                int64
Age                  int64
Income               int64
Location             int64
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

If the list of column names comes as a string in exactly this format, you could do:

```
with open(file2) as f:
    list_of_columns=f.read()
list_of_columns = ['date'] + list_of_columns[5:-1].split(',')
list_of_columns = [l.strip() for l in list_of_columns] # remove leading/trailing whitespace
df=pd.read_csv(file1, sep='/t', names=list_of_columns)
```